# Azure B2C Microsoft Login Page is not confirming with ADA rules

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

Azure B2C Microsoft Login Page is not confirming with ADA rules. Here are the issues with the page:
1.On the Sign Up page, there are “What is this?” links for each field like Name, Email ,etc. These links are not associated with their respective label.
2.Arrow focus is not going to the static content of all 'What is this' dialog upon activating.
Troubleshooting steps taken so far: We cannot do much on our side as the code needs to be changed my Microsoft on their login page.
Impact to client: We are using the Microsoft Login Page in a portal where thousands of users log in some of whom might have visual challenges. They have difficulty signing up or signing into the B2C login screen because of not meeting the ADA requirements.
Example URL: : https://statefarmdemo.e4ereleafuat.org/;

There are 2 issues here:

If you look behind the scene in the HTML code – the “What is this” links do not have arial-label. More info here: https://www.washington.edu/accessibility/links/
When you click on the “What is this” link, it opens a pop up. But the content in the pop up is not accessible for people who might have visual issues. They would expect to be able to tab into the content in the pop up and have JAWS or another speech software call out the message. This is not possible at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

In the default template experience *"What is this"* does not exists. Please note that ADA standards can be met in different ways but all customized scenarios may not be met. It's not uncommon for companies to take strict approach to go beyond what is needed or required per this regulation.

> If you look behind the scene in the HTML code – the “What is this”
> links do not have arial-label. More info here:
> https://www.washington.edu/accessibility/links/

There is no need to put aria-label behind the scene in the HTML code as the Narrator can detect the link text and announce it which meets this requirement.

> When you click on the “What is this” link, it opens a pop up. But the
> content in the pop up is not accessible for people who might have
> visual issues.

It is accessible from keyboard for Chrome + Windows Narrator.

> They would expect to be able to tab into the content in the pop up and
> have JAWS or another speech software call out the message. This is not
> possible at the moment.

Narrator will announce the message from the pop up.

> These links are not associated with their respective label.

From the pop up, the message is related to the control.

> Troubleshooting steps taken so far: We cannot do much on our side as
> the code needs to be changed my Microsoft on their login page.

You can apply your custom JavaScript and change anything they want for better accessibility.

Comment: Thanks Chad, it looks like the content is announced by Windows Narrator but is not by JAWS. Do you know if Microsoft B2C will not support JAWS?
thanks.

Comment: any help please?